# Java decrease stack size to save memory

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm

I want to decrease memory footprint of Java application in order to decrease swapping. I've been thinking about decreasing stack size (Xss parameter) for this purpose, but not sure how stack memory is allocated and whether the default 512k (for 32 bit OS) per thread sits always in resident memory regardless of how much of it is actually used.

Will decreasing stack memory lead to decrease of swapping?

Update: Please don't suggest to profile the application - it is already done.

Comment: What has lead you to believe the stack size is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that there is not enough ram and some memory is need to be cut and i don't see how i can cut from heap or perm gen

Comment: The first step to fixing this problem is to profile the application. Until you know what is taking up memory you're essentially guessing and will very likely end up spending time on a non-existent problem.  A profiler will give you direct information on what is taking up the memory in your application and it's probably something you don't expect to be doing so.

Comment: This is done, still using swap

Comment: But what did the profiler tell you?  It seems **very** unlikely that it faulted the stack size

Comment: Again, I profiled my application and I can't cut from my heap any further, therefore my question is specific about stack

Comment: That seems hard to believe though. Every object in your heap can't be shrunk at all?

Comment: I bag your pardon, but the discussion about the heap of the application seems useless to me.

Comment: @ArtiomGourevitch No your question isn't specific about the stack because you refer to the heap and permgen. If the stack size has been identified as the problem then you already seem aware of how to decrease it. If it hasn't been identified as the problem then what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I removed the line about perm gen and heap. My question is whether decreasing stack will decrease the swapping as well?

Answer (score 5):

How many threads are you running?  Even with a huge number of threads and a very generous stack size (say, 10k threads and 256KB stack size) that's only 2GB of heap space.

You say you are running on a 32bit JVM, so I assume this is a relatively small system.  You have a few options:

- Switch to a 64bit JVM.  Now you have tons of address space and the stack size should be inconsequential
- Your machine is too small.  If the 2gb of stack is a problem for your 10k+ threads, you are running too "big" of an application on too "small" of a machine.  Do less in software or buy more hardware
- Reduce your thread count
- The problem is actually elsewhere and you are barking up the wrong tree

Comment: The OP claims that it's swapping, meaning that it doesn't run out of address space, but rather physical memory. Wouldn't switching to 64bit only make that problem worse?

Comment: It is a memory constrained environment. Xmx value is 640 MB, there are hundreds of threads

Comment: @Artiom *Hundreds* of threads? Only a pretty powerful server could service such a large number of threads at the same time. You probably should look into ThreadPools.

Comment: @trutheality:  Yeah, it would just make it worse, you're right.  But then the only answer is to reduce the number of threads or increase the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will of course its lifo rule last in first out , less stack less swap

Answer (score 0):

How much memory are you using and how much do you need to save?

Since the stack is only 512K per thread, it means you would need 200 Threads to start entering a value that might be worth saving (100Mb)

Since the use of stack memory would be 'very often' I would consider it a bad target for being swapped out. Unless you are dealing with a memory constrained environment?

Comment: Exactly, it is a memory constrained environment

Comment: Damn, I forgot to mention. The easiest thing to do would be to try it and actually see if it helps.
I seen that your app is set to use 640mb but how much memory does the target machine have?

Comment: This is difficult to calculate, there are other processes running on that machine as well that have their memory consumption less defined. Besides it is difficult to say how much memory does the operating system itself need.

Comment: Then this question becomes less about managing java and more about managing a server. If you stop all of the services and test the memory usage, you'll get an idea of what the OS is using. You still haven't mentioned how much memory the server has. How many other processes are on the machine?
At some point you have to overload the server...